# Check if file name contains IP address and get the free file name PHP

Tags: php, ip-address, php-7.4

I am trying to check if files in a directory contain a specific ip address. If the IP address is not found in the file name I want a file with the not found IP adress in the file name to be moved there.

Here's my script:

```php
<?php

function ip_range($start = "10.100.1.2", $end = "10.100.255.254"){
    $start = ip2long($start);
    $end = ip2long($end);
    return array_map('long2ip', range($start, $end));
}
function check_filename(){

    $ip_address_list = ip_range();
    $dir_files = scandir("/mnt/dumps/");
    foreach($ip_address_list as $ip){
        foreach($dir_files as $file){
            if($d = glob($ip)){
                if(empty($d)){
                    $fpath = "/mnt/dumps/{$ip}_public.txt";
                    echo $fpath;
            }
        }
        if(isset($fpath)){
            return $fpath;
        }
        if(isset($fpath)){
            return $fpath;
        }

    }

};

?>
```

But when I execute the script it returns me as example 10.100.1.2 - but a file containing this IP address already exists. That's actually not what I want.

Could you tell me what I've did wrong? Thanks!

### EDIT:

I've changed the script:

```php
function ip_range($start = "10.100.1.2", $end = "10.100.255.254"){
    $start = ip2long($start);
    $end = ip2long($end);
    return array_map('long2ip', range($start, $end));
}

function check_filename(){

    $ip_address_list = ip_range();
    $dir_files = scandir("/mnt/dumps/");
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($dir_files); echo "</pre>";
    foreach($ip_address_list as $ip){
        $new_ip = preg_quote($ip);
        foreach($dir_files as $file){
            if(!preg_match("/^{$new_ip}_public.{0,10}\.txt/", $file)){
                $fpath = "/mnt/dumps/{$ip}_public.txt";
            }
        }
        if(isset($fpath)){
            return $fpath;
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: Probably you have to change this:
[code]
if($d = glob($file, "{$ip}") == false)

Comment: @ChrisHaas I edited my script now to `if($d = glob($ip)){
                if(empty($d)){
                    $fpath = "/mnt/dumps/{$ip}_public.txt";
                    echo $fpath;
                    print_r($d);
                    return;`

Comment: Edited - but It still doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Is the folder with these files well structured? If so, can you just use `file_exists`? `$test_path = "/foo/bar/{$ip}.txt";if (!file_exists($test_path)) {/*Move file here*/}`

Comment: @ChrisHaas not really. Files have names like `10.100.1.2_public.txt` and `10.100.1.2_public@2.txt`. That's why I tried it with regex

Answer (score 0):

Probaby you have to modify the IF from

```
if($d = glob($file, "{$ip}") == false)
```

to

```
if($file == $ip)
```

PS. check the documentation for glob: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php